# Reducing delay between System.Timers.TImer calls

Tags: c#, serilog, csvhelper, system.timers.timer

I am storing OHLC data real-time in a CSV file for which I am using a `System.Timers.Timer` to trigger every 60 seconds. Timer is something like this:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 60000;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += TimeElapsed;
timer.Start();

private void TimeElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.Timer.ElapsedEventArgs e){
    // Do some Processing here
}
```

I have been using a Serilog logger to log the output each time this event is triggered and notices one thing that the timer is adding a bit delay (a few milliseconds after every call) and then since the code is running for a long time now like close to 2 days that milliseconds accumulate to make few seconds now. First Entry was at 2023-09-20 21:17:00.363 and now since it is being called every minute, now the call every minute is happening at 2023-09-22 13:46:27.504. Notice an addition of 27 seconds over time. I don't want that. So is there a way to map timer with your windows clock? Or can you suggest a better approach of doing that? Do note that I want it to store in the csv file @HH:MM:00 time only.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer timer is declared inside a separate function. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You are appending to a file and as the file grows larger the time will also increase.

Comment: Yes I am appending to file but keeping a limited number of records only (1340 to be precise at max) and deleting once the size is more than that. I guess this should not be the issue because even after deleing it it is increasing

Comment: It still takes time to truncate file to 1340 lines.  When you only have a few lines the time is small but as the file grows to 1340 the time will increase and then become constant.

Comment: As long as it doesn't take 60 seconds to truncate and write the file, I don't think that is the issue.  System.Timers.Timer is not guaranteed to be exactly precise and you will get drift over time.  You will need to check the system time and re-synchronize your timer each time.  See the solutions in my link above.

Comment: @jdweng Its not becoming constant. My code cleared excess data when the market was closed and it left only 200 lines there. Note that 1340 mark was touched already and then it cleared the file. Now 200 lines are there so according to your point it should not exceed the timer but it is still doing that.

Comment: @DavidSpecht in the above question that you mentioned notice the output result of Top answer and see there is a millisecond addition with each call. These milliseconds are adding up to make a huge difference basically.

Comment: @DharuvVerma21 On the answer, Jared only showed the first 4 times.  Jared also said, "On my box this code ticks consistently within .02s of each minute:"  I think if Jared had shown more than 4, you would have seen no time going past 2 milliseconds of the system time's minute.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 20 milliseconds.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Thanks I just tried that and it worked. Thanks for the help.